Confusion about the difference between cotangent bundle to partial flag variety and partial resolution of the nilpotent cone
Formula (3.7) of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.00107 identifies the cotangent bundle of the partial flag variety as variety of partial flags and nilpotents such that the partial flag is preserved by the nilpotent. On page 27 of the paper http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1983__101-102__23_0.pdf the partial resolution of the nilpotent cone is defined as pairs of nilpotent and partial flag such that nilpotent preserves the partial flag. The two definitions seem to be exactly the same, which cannot be because cotangent bundle to partial flag variety as smooth and partial resolution of nilpotent cone may be singular. What is wrong with my reasoning?
